# Как работать с неизвестной структурой JSON?

Tags: java

есть ли возможность работать с заранее неизвестной структурой JSON?

знаю такой способ:

```
Json json = new Json();
MyClass myJson = json.fromJson(MyClass.class, str);
```

но для него надо знать структуру JSON и создать иерархию классов,
а что делать если структура json файла заранее не известна, можно ли ее обработать?

для примера в JS можно любой json преобразовать в объект и обработать его поля в цикле

`UPDATE`

разговор про сложную структуру:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "my name",
    "options": {
        "desc":"text",
        "flags": [1,3,5],
        "object" : {
            "field1":"value",
            "field2":"value2",
            "field3":"value2"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В случае с jackson можно просто сконвертировать в Object, а тот окажется либо List, либо Map

Comment: Скорее всего, вашим решением в идеале будет не класс, а нечто вроде вложенных нодов. Сгенерировать класс в реалтайме, вроде как реально, но, работать с этим классом будет на порядок сложнее, чем с распарсеными строковыми данными из json... В общем, в Json библиотеке явы, вы можете обращаться к полям как к строкам, и это будет на порядок проще чем рефлексировать меняющий на ходу свою структуру класс...

Comment: @test123, обновил вопрос. Можно ли обработать сложный json не зная заранее его структуру?

Comment: @ravend Т.е. ты совсем не знаешь его структуру?? А зачем он тогда нужен? :) На вход приходит то, не знаю что, но оттуда я хочу что-то. Опиши пожалуйста, что ты с этим json хочешь делать? Пробежаться по нему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Gson есть следующий способ:

```
JsonElement prs = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
```

У него есть методы для проверки типа сущностей в json. Например:

```
prs.isJsonObject()
prs.isJsonArray()
```

и так далее.

Засчёт этого вы можете вручную пройтись по элементам json'а и достать информацию, которая Вам нужна. В других json парсерах должно быть что-то аналогичное.

Comment: С массивом понятно. А можно обратиться к N-ому члену объекта? По индексу например? Если я точно не знаю его структуру

Comment: Можно итерироваться по филдам: prs.getAsJsonObject().entrySet(), где результатом будет Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>>